# Tutorial or sample code about UITableView in UIScrollView

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, uiscrollview

I just want to add UITableView to the one page of my multi-page UIScrollView. I know it's not very complicated but I teaching new things better when I saw some example code. I heard there are some tricky things when you insert UITableView in a UIScrollView like properties delaysContentTouches and canCancelContentTouches have to be set appropriately etc. So if anyone knows good tutorial about that or just sample code - it would be nice. Thx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UITableView inherited from UIScrollView, hense you want to make nested UIScrollViews. [Read short article on developer.apple.com](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/UIScrollView_pg/NestedScrollViews/NestedScrollViews.html) about that:

> Your application does not need to do
> anything to support
> (cross-directional) nesting scrolling.
> It is supported and provided by
> default.
>
> Same-direction scrolling is supported,
> and there is a distinct behavior
> defined for the functionality, however
> that behavior is subject to change in
> future versions of iOS.

That is why you should just add your UITableView as subView to your UIScrollView.